# Login with OAuth & retrieve user details from DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm new to OAuth. Does anyone know how to login with OAuth, I have managed to generate a token by passing user name and password and used sessionStorage.setItem('accessToken') in javascript to store the token,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnLogin').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/token',
                method: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: {
                    username: $('#txtEmail').val(),
                    password: $('#txtPassword').val(),
                    grant_type: 'password'
                },
                success: function (response) {

                    sessionStorage.setItem('accessToken', response.access_token);
                    sessionStorage.setItem('userName', response.userName);
                    window.location.href = "Jobs.html";

                },
                error: function (jqXHR) {
                    $('#divErrorText').text(jqXHR.responseText);
                    $('#divError').show('fade');
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

This is my custom OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        //find a match with the entered username and password
        AppUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
        if(user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("Access Denied, Invalid Username or Password");
            return;
        }

        //responsible to fetch the authenticated user identity from the database and returns an object of type “ClaimsIdentity”
        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        ClaimsIdentity cookieIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);

        context.Validated(ticket);
        context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookieIdentity);
    }
```

how can I log the user in and How can I retrieve the username and email from the DB without using sessionStorage.getItem. Do I need to call another LogIn API for this? (something like this)

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> LogIn(LogInModel model)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View();
        }
userManager.FindAsync.
        var user = await userManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);

        // sign in the user using the cookie authentication middleware  SignIn(identity)
        if (user != null)
        {
            await SignIn(user);
            return Redirect(GetRedirectUrl(model.ReturnUrl));
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Kas Error Message -Inavlid email or password");
        return View();
    }

 private async Task SignIn(AppUser user)
    {
        var identity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(
            user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        GetAuthenticationManager().SignIn(identity);
    }
```

Sorry if I sound thick :) any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

When you created a Web API project and selected to use ASP.Net Identity it should have generated an AccountController class containing the API calls you need, such as `GetUserInfo()`. Looks like you have to perform a separate call to get the user details, not sure if there's an easy way to combine the call for performing log in and then returning user details with the access token.